# OpenGL: Rendering on transparent framebuffer with blending

Tags: c++, opengl, transparency, framebuffer, blending

I would like to perform renders with blending on a transparent frame buffer.
So generally the standard

```
SRCa * SRCrgb + (1 - SRCa) * DSTrgb
```

color blending works well, as long as you assume the destination alpha always is one.
Drawing on a transparent frame buffer leaves artifacts, as the source color is being blent with a color, which isn't displayed in the first place.

The solution to that would be pretty simple. I could multiply a destination color with a destination alpha so it wouldn't be blent if the DSTa is zero.
The ideal equation would be something like:

```
SRCrgb * (1 - (1 - SRCa) * DSTa) + DSTrgb * (1 - SRCa) * DSTa
```

But OpenGL won't let me do that easily. I'm really disappointed with OpenGL blending.

Is there some kind of OpenGL trick that would let me draw on a transparent frame buffer with standard blending? (Of course I can just disable the blending, but the point is to make it work with a filled frame buffer as well; The content of a buffer is not certain, it may be transparent, it may be not.)

I have only two ideas, which are to draw whatever is displayed behind the transparent frame buffer. Which would cause more problems, than it would fix.
The other would be to perform such blending with a fragment shader, which is a lot hassle unfortunately.

Is there some other way?

Comment: You just need your buffer to be premultiplied - each pixel color must be premultiplied by its alpha. Then usual GL_SRC_ALPHA / GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA should do what you want. Probably, you'll have to output your geometry with premultiplied alpha as well. To do so you should multiply output color by its alpha and use GL_ONE / GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA blending.

Comment: Read about [Alpha Compositing, OpenGL Blending and Premultiplied Alpha](http://apoorvaj.io/alpha-compositing-opengl-blending-and-premultiplied-alpha.html#toc5)

Comment: Have you solved it? I am having the same problem.